# Wordpress saving button is doing something weird

Tags: php, wordpress

Every time I use saving button from post editor in wordpress, my browser asks me if I want to leave the page.

I have a few plugins installed, I'm developing a new one. It never happened to me before working on wordpress.

I'm using `wp_insert_post` hook to do some things every time I save post/page.

**EDIT 1**

Every time I update a single post, browser shows me an alert telling me If I want to leave the page. I discovered, that the plugin that cause this alert to show it's YOAST.

Can you please give a hand, and tell me what do I have to do to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Ismael

Comment: Does the problem still occur when you disable all your plugins (including the one you're developing)?

Comment: I catch the plugin that cause this issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to do something every time you publish or update a post in wordpress you have to use [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post):

for example if you want to send an email every time a post or page is updated on your website.

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id ) {

    // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $subject = 'A post has been updated';

    $message = "A post has been updated on your website:\n\n";
    $message .= $post_title . ": " . $post_url;

    // Send email to admin.
    wp_mail( 'admin@example.com', $subject, $message );

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' );
```

Comment: I discard this hook, because it didn't work for me with the libraries I've using.

Comment: may i know your libraries or maybe what you want to achieve, and `wp_insert_post ` isn't a hook, @IsmaelMoral

Comment: I'm using `Timber` to enable twig inside wordpress core, and `wp_insert_post` is a hook https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/

Comment: sorry, right it is action hook. but i cant understand what you want to achieve maybe you can explain it bit more in your question @IsmaelMoral

Comment: I simply use this hook, because it fires after post data is saved inside database. The problem is every time I update a published post, my browser asks me if I want to leave the page.

Comment: think i found the problem, may i see your code, you are doing a redirect or reload there?, this action hook is firing before data being saved in database not after, you can alter post data before being inserted into database.